# What is (->) in Haskell?

Tags: function, haskell, constructor, functor

If you type `:i (->)` in GHCi and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> it returns the following:

```
data (->) t1 t2     -- Defined in ‘GHC.Prim’
infixr 0 `(->)`
instance Monad ((->) r) – Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
instance Functor ((->) r) – Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
instance Applicative ((->) a) – Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
instance Monoid b => Monoid (a -> b) – Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
```

Judging by the `data` keyword, it's a type constructor of some kind, but what exactly does it construct and what are the value constructors for this type, if they exist?

The question arose when I learned that functions are part of the `Functor` type class and are listed as `((->) r)` in the type class description returned by the `:i Functor` command. I tried to get information about `((->) r)`, but to no avail. Then, in the description of the `Functor` type class, I spotted `(Either a)` (whose description can be obtained with `:i Either`, i.e. without the parameter) and realized that I should try `:i (->)` instead, which I did and got the information shown above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's simply the function type constructor.

The type `(->) a b`, which is more often written in infix form as `a -> b`, is the type of function which takes the type `a` as argument and returns the type `b`. You'll see this in the type signature of any function.

Like most other things in `GHC.Prim`, it's built in and a little bit "magical", in the sense that it doesn't have value constructors - but you can define a  value of type `a -> b`, that is a function, in all the ways I expect you already know about.

Comment: I suppose a function value is always _constructed_ using a lambda expression `\ pattern -> expression` or syntactic sugar for that. It’s just that there’s no pattern for _deconstructing_ a function—all you can really do with a function in Haskell is apply it to an argument.

Answer (score 2):

I want to point out the kind of `(->)`. If you ask ghci it will tell you its arguments are (lifted) `Type`s

```
ghci> :k (->)
(->) :: Type -> Type -> Type
```

But if you print explicit runtime representations, you will see that it accepts arguments of [`TYPE`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/GHC-Exts.html#t:TYPE)

```hs
ghci> :set -fprint-explicit-runtime-reps
ghci> import GHC.Exts
ghci> :k (->)
(->) :: forall {rep1 :: RuntimeRep} {rep2 :: RuntimeRep}.
        TYPE rep1 -> TYPE rep2 -> Type
```

parameterised by [`RuntimeRep`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/GHC-Exts.html#t:RuntimeRep)

```
type RuntimeRep :: Type
data RuntimeRep
  = BoxedRep Levity -- ^ boxed; represented by a pointer
  | IntRep          -- ^ signed, word-sized value
  | Int8Rep         -- ^ signed,  8-bit value
  | ..
  | FloatRep        -- ^ a 32-bit floating point number
  | DoubleRep       -- ^ a 64-bit floating point number

-- | Whether a boxed type is lifted or unlifted.
type Levity :: Type
data Levity = Lifted | Unlifted
```

[`Type`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-Kind.html#t:Type) is actually a synonym for

```hs
type Type :: Type
type Type = TYPE LiftedRep
```

where [`LiftedRep`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/GHC-Exts.html#t:LiftedRep) is a synonym for runtime representations that are boxed and lifted (this is most types in Haskell, like `Int` or `Bool`).

```hs
type LiftedRep :: RuntimeRep
type LiftedRep = BoxedRep Lifted
```

By being polymorphic over the runtime representation, `(->)` can accept unboxed arguments like `Int# :: TYPE IntRep` and `Double# :: TYPE DoubleRep`, and other weird types with unusual representations:

```hs
ghci> :set -XMagicHash
ghci> :k Int# -> Double#
Int# -> Double# :: Type
```

Further more, since the linear types extension, `(->)` is actually a type synonym for [`FUN`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-Kind.html#t:FUN),

```hs
FUN :: Multiplicity -> TYPE rep1 -> TYPE rep2 -> Type
```

applied to the "[`Many :: Multiplicity`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/GHC-Exts.html#t:Multiplicity)"

```hs
type (->) :: forall {rep1} {rep2}. TYPE rep1 -> TYPE rep2 -> Type 
type (->) = FUN Many
```